# Is there a short phrase/ slang for " hating the people you love most"?

Tags: translation, expressions, slang

I'm looking for a phrase that means something that means something along "I hate the people I love the most"
I know 愛憎関係 means love-hate relationship but was wondering if there was something closer to what Im looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say 可愛さ余って憎さ百倍 is a good contender (when you love something a lot, your hatred will also be strong once you start to hate it).